# Why does False==False in [False] return True?

Tags: python

A senior of mine demonstrated it and I want to know if this is a flaw or is there some precedence and operator associativity stuff that justifies it.

```
>>> False==False in [False]
True
```

Comment: This could be a case of Python's famous comparison operator chaining (so that this would be the same as `False == False and False in [False]`). I'm not sure about that though...

Comment: Without knowing, but from the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34163067/python-why-does-false-false-in-false-returns-true#34163067 - it might be due to the way it is handled. `(False==False) in [False]`

Comment: substituting `False` with `1` makes it a lot more clearer

Comment: @letsc: No it doesn't, because `False` is numerically 0, not 1.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham no matter what precedence is, `(False == False) in [False]` and `False == (False in [False])` are both `False`. So, it's chaining.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Python's [comparison operators](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in) chain.

```
False == False in [False]
```

is evaluated as

```
(False == False) and (False in [False])
```

The middle term participates in both comparisons.

I would prefer that `in` not chain with the other comparison operators.

Comment: Is the only reason for chaining operators to make expressions like `x < y < z` legal? Because if that's the case although it's handy, it seems like that's a small benefit in exchange for confusing code like `(False==False in [False])==True` being legal.

Comment: I don't know of a use case for chaining `in` with other comparison operators that produces clear code.

Comment: Steven, you can avoid trying to shoot yourself in the foot by simply not doing stupid stuff like this. Nobody is forcing you to write unmaintainable code :-)